# Android - RecyclerView and Zoom Image

Tags: android, image, view, zooming, android-recyclerview

I have image in item of my recyclerview and i would like to zoom in/out on click. I tried to implements [Zooming a View](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) but unsuccessfully, onclick image become invisible but nothing else..

Maybe this isn't compatible with RecyclerView ?
What should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

In simple case this example should work fine with RecyclerView, but it is hard to say what causes the problem in your case without looking into your code.

Alternatively you can try to use [this image viewer library](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews), looks like it should do exactly what you want (animate image from RecyclerView into full mode and back again).

(Note, I'm the author of that library)